# How to extract columns given parts of the name

Tags: r, dataframe

Given a dataframe with columns names:

```
"openPrice1", "closePrice1", "openPrice2", "closePrice2", "openPrice3", "closePrice3"...
```

How can I extract all columns that contain `"open"`?

For example I want a new dataframe:

```
"openPrice1", "openPrice2", "openPrice3" ...
```

Comment: Try `df1[startsWith(names(df1), "open")]`or `df1[grep("^open", names(df1))]`

Answer (score 0):

Either we can use `startsWith`

```
df1[startsWith(names(df1), "open")]
```

Or use `grep`

```
df1[grep("^open", names(df1))]
```

Both are `base R` options

---

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   select(starts_with('open')
```